# how to use sqlalchemy for sql?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

select category_id, (select category.name from category where category.id = category_id ) as category_name from ( select distinct category_id as category_id from model join category on ( category.id = model.category_id)  ) as R

...
self.current_session.query(Model.category_id).join(Category).distinct()

But how to know category_name ?

Comment: Step 1.  Format your code using `{}`.  Step 2.  Clarify your question with -- perhaps -- the actual error message you're actually getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for model, category in self.current_session.query(Model, Category).join(Category).distinct():
    print model.category_id, category.name
```